# Exhaustive Concatenation between the tensors

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, attention-model

I am trying to do the exhaustive concatenation between the tensors. So, for example,
I have tensor:

`a = torch.randn(3, 512)`

I want to concatenate like
concat(t1,t1),concat(t1,t2), concat(t1,t3), concat(t2,t1), concat(t2,t2)....

As a naive solution,
I have used `for` loop:

```
ans = []
result = []
split = torch.split(a, [1, 1, 1], dim=0)

for i in range(len(split)):
    ans.append(split[i])

for t1 in ans:
    for t2 in ans:
        result.append(torch.cat((t1,t2), dim=1))
```

The issue is that each epoch is taking very long time and the code is slow. 
I tried the solution posted in question on [PyTorch: How to implement attention for graph attention layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358396/pytorch-how-to-implement-attention-for-graph-attention-layer) but this gives a memory error.

```
t1 = a.repeat(1, a.shape[0]).view(a.shape[0] * a.shape[0], -1)
t2 = a.repeat(a.shape[0], 1)
result.append(torch.cat((t1, t2), dim=1))
```

I am sure there is a faster way, but I was unable to figure it out.

Comment: What is the context? What are you going to do with the `result`? Right now, you're creating 9 1x1024 matrices, which requires a plenty of memory - if in your actual usecase you're concatenating even more sub-tensors, your memory consumption grows quadratically - it's not surprising this is slow. I don't see how the answer from attention for graph layers relates to your problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jatentaki I am trying to concatenate the tensors with all other tensors actually. That is all what I want to achieve. I know it is slow. I was just trying to say that maybe converting the tensors using `repeat` might help as illustrated in other post of stackoverflow. But it is still memory error. Is there any simpler way to achiever concatenation. `result` will be converted to tensor and will be passed through linear layer.

Comment: Can you post the code which results in memory error so we can reproduce?

Comment: @Jatentaki Edited. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jatentaki The code which gives the memory error also consumes lot of memory and it grows quadratically. But I am not sure how to do this any other way.

Comment: This does not result in memory errors on my machine. If by memory error you mean that you're running out of memory, perhaps you just have to look for a different approach to what you're trying to do.